# How do I get a default tmux configuration file?

Tags: tmux

I installed `tmux` via `apt-get` and there is no `.tmux.conf` file in my home directory, even after I run `tmux`.

I have been trying to follow a tmux tutorial, but the first part involves modifying this file, but since I do not have this file I am stuck. How do I get the tmux conf file?

Comment: I created https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux to help people get started with tmux

Comment: @GregoryPakosz: Oh my god it's oh-my-tmux!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There should be several example configuration files in either `/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples` or `/usr/share/tmux/`. You can copy any of those over to `~/.tmux.conf` to test out.

Alternatively, you could create a `~/.tmux.conf` with the default settings by using this command from within tmux:

```
tmux show -g > ~/.tmux.conf
```

This command works with tmux version 1.8.

In older versions of `tmux`, a bug regarding redirecting stdout to a file might require this command:

```
tmux show -g | cat > ~/.tmux.conf
```

More info can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192401/where-is-the-default-tmux-conf-file-located).

Comment: Why is the `| cat` part necessary?

Comment: It's not, at least in tmux 1.8. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I strongly suggest learning/teaching long forms of commands. Short forms tend to be very difficult to search for. Try searching http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tmux.1.html for `show-options` then search for `show`.

Comment: Strange to note for the most, but happened to me: I thought the command would be run from the Linux normal terminal. You need to run it inside tmux.

Answer (score 12):

If the `.tmux.conf` file does not exist, then you can simply create it.  `tmux` would read it the next time you start `tmux`.

The rest of this answer concerns figuring out what the "default options" are, but note that you don't *really* need this unless you're interested in what they are.

The `tmux` utility's own `show-options` command with the `-g` flag will dump all the globally set options *in the current `tmux` session* (i.e., `tmux` has to be running to use it).

So if you're in a `tmux` session, your `~/.tmux.conf` file is empty, then the following will dump out the default settings:

```
$ tmux show-options -g >tmux.conf-default
```

Some options are set by `tmux` by inspecting the shell environment. I, for example, get `status-keys vi`, presumably because I use Vi key bindings in my shell (`EDITOR` is set to `vim`).

In any case, you'll get the options that way. However, I've noticed that there is *very little* that I ever have to configure in `tmux`.  I find it well set up by default for my taste, and I basically just re-set the prefix key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (the <kbd>b</kbd> key is one step too far to the right for comfort on my Dvorak keyboard), and that's that.

If you don't need/want to change anything in the default options, then you don't need a `.tmux.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

if installed through homebrew then path would be "/usr/local/Cellar/tmux/2.8/share/tmux"

And in this location there would be a example conf file, you can create a new tmux.conf file at this location and then execute the following command
"tmux source-file tmux.conf"

Comment: Never would have found this, thank you! Also, it varies by version, for example: `/usr/local/Cellar/tmux/3.2a_1/share/tmux/example_tmux.conf`